# Testing simple Redux-Form with Enzyme (where is value??)

Tags: reactjs, redux, enzyme, redux-form

I have the most simple redux-form connected to redux example :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class TestForm extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <Field component={Input} name={'testField'}/>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

class Input extends React.PureComponent {
    render(): React.Node {
        let { input } = this.props;
        // input = {name: 'testField', value: 'test value'};
        return (
                <input name={input.name} value={input.value} type='text' onChange={()=>1}/>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ testForm }) => {
    return {
        initialValues: testForm,
    };
};

export const TestFormWithReduxForm = reduxForm({ form: 'test form'})(TestForm);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TestFormWithReduxForm);
```

Note the following :

- I have my own custom Input (called Input)
- I am connecting to reduxForm, and then connecting to redux.
- The initial values that are passed in should have 'name' and 'value'.

I have the following test (Jest+Enzyme)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Enzyme, { mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';

import TestForm from './TestForm';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('Redux Form Test', () => {
    let wrapper;

    let mockStoreData = {
        testForm: {
            testField: 'test value',
        },
    };

    const mockStore = configureStore();
    const store = mockStore(mockStoreData);

    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = mount(
            <Provider store={store}>
                    <TestForm />
            </Provider>
        );
    });

    it('Check Value', () => {
        let inputs = wrapper.find('input');
        expect(inputs.at(0).prop('name')).toBe('testField'); //OK!!!
        expect(inputs.at(0).prop('value')).toBe('test value'); //empty string!!
    });
});
```

The Jest test passes in a 'testForm' object with 'testField' (and its value) into the the store.

As expected, the name on the first input is 'testField', however the 'value' is empty (ie. an empty string).

This is not expected, because if I were to render the component in a normal page then 'test value' would appear.

So something seems to be broken here. I am not sure if it has something to do with redux-form or enzyme, but the redux-form Field object seems to be intercepting the properties that are passed into the Input object.

I am starting to question whether it is even ***possible*** to test **redux form**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want nor need to test Redux Form's functionality, as it's already been tested by the creators/maintainers. However, `redux-mock-store` appears to be made for `unit` tests only (where you'll mock `middlewares` and call `store.dispatch(actionType)` and expect the `action` to be called). It doesn't handle `reducer` side effects nor track changes in `state`.

**In the case above, you'll only need to do a unit test on your custom `Input` component, because that's the only component that's different from what would be considered a standard redux form.**

That said... for an `integration` test, you'll need to use a real `store` that contains the redux-form's `reducer` and your `field` state.

**Working example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/zl4p5w26xm (I've included a `Form` integration test and an `Input` unit test -- as you'll notice, the `Input` unit test covers most of your testing needs)

**containers/Form/Form.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Form, Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Input from "../../components/Input/input";

const isRequired = value => (!value ? "Required" : undefined);

class SimpleForm extends Component {
  handleFormSubmit = formProps => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(formProps, null, 4));
  };

  render = () => (
    <div className="form-container">
      <h1 className="title">Text Field</h1>
      <hr />
      <Form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit)}>
        <Field
          className="uk-input"
          name="testField"
          component={Input}
          type="text"
          validate={[isRequired]}
        />
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-large submit"
          disabled={this.props.submitting}
        >
          Submit
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="uk-button uk-button-default uk-button-large reset"
          disabled={this.props.pristine || this.props.submitting}
          onClick={this.props.reset}
          style={{ float: "right" }}
        >
          Clear
        </button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default connect(({ field }) => ({
  initialValues: { [field.name]: field.value }
}))(
  reduxForm({
    form: "SimpleForm"
  })(SimpleForm)
);
```

**containers/Form/__test__/Form.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import SimpleForm from "../Form";
import store from "../../../store/store";

const wrapper = mount(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <SimpleForm />
  </Provider>
);

describe("Redux Form Test", () => {
  it("renders without errors", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(".form-container")).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  it("fills the input with a default value", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find("input").prop("name")).toBe("testField");
    expect(wrapper.find("input").prop("value")).toBe("Test Value");
  });

  it("updates input value when changed", () => {
    const event = { target: { value: "Test" } };
    wrapper.find("input").simulate("change", event);
    expect(wrapper.find("input").prop("value")).toBe("Test");
  });

  it("resets the input value to defaults when the Clear button has been clicked", () => {
    wrapper.find("button.reset").simulate("click");
    expect(wrapper.find("input").prop("value")).toBe("Test Value");
  });
});
```

**stores/stores.js** (for simplicity, I lumped `reducers` and `store` into one file)

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";
import { reducer as formReducer } from "redux-form";

const initialValues = {
  name: "testField",
  value: "Test Value"
};

const fieldReducer = (state = initialValues, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
const reducer = combineReducers({
  field: fieldReducer,
  form: formReducer
});

export default createStore(reducer);
```

Note: Aside from using `initialValues`, buried in the documentation, there are three other ways to update field values: Utilizing redux-form's [reducer.plugin](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/api/reducerplugin.md/) and dispatching an action to update the form, or by using `this.props.intialize({ testField: "Test Value" });` with `enableReinitialize: true` and `keepDirtyOnReinitialize: true,`, or by using `this.props.change("SimpleForm", { testField: "Test Value" });`. Important to note because sometimes `mapStateToProps` is asynchronous.

Comment: do you know if its possible to download all the files at once from codepen? I wouldn't mind playing around with what you have written.

Comment: ok nevermind, i got your codepen working in my IDE. Thanks heaps :) It works! I think the 'take home' for me was that the redux-mock-store is what my problem was. ReduxForm has its own little reducer that the test needs to know about, so in that sense you need a proper store to test it....

Comment: on a side note, i think it is a pretty important test :) Having data fields not matching up with field 'names' is one of the biggest problems I have. Having a test which secures all these fields is pretty important IMO