# How do you debug a shallow rendered enzyme test?

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, react-redux, enzyme

I am trying to fix a failing test in my react-redux app. When I dive and dive again into my component, I expect to see the JSX within it. However, I don't see anything.

Here is my component -

```
      const Dashboard = (props) => {
          if (props.isSignedIn)
            return (
              <div className="dashboard">
                  <h1>Welcome</h1>
              </div>
            );
          return null;
        };

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return { isSignedIn: state.auth.isSignedIn };
    };
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { signIn, signOut })(Dashboard);
```

Here is my failing test :-

```
const setup = (initialState = {}) => {
  const store = storeFactory(initialState);
  const wrapper = shallow(<Dashboard store={store} />).dive().dive();
  return wrapper;
};

describe("on render", () => {
describe("the user is signed in", () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    const initialState = { isSignedIn: true };
    wrapper = setup(initialState);
  });
  it("renders the dashboard", () => {
    const component = wrapper.find("dashboard");
    expect(component.length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

My store factory :-

```
export const storeFactory = (initialState) => {
  const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)(createStore);
  console.log(initialState);
  return createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer, initialState);
};
```

My test error :-

```
● the user is signed in › renders the dashboard

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 1
    Received: 0
```

When I dive one time it looks like this :-

```
 <Dashboard store={{...}} isSignedIn={{...}} signIn={[Function]} signOut={[Function]} />}
```

but when I try to see the JSX inside of the dashboard component I see nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your setup isn't working because you're trying to `shallow` mount a redux connected component -- which is a higher-order component (HOC) wrapping another component that can't be properly `dive`d into due to enzyme's shallow limitations.

Instead, you have two options:

Option 1.) **Recommended**: Export the `Dashboard` component and make assertions against it using `shallow` or `mount` (I mostly use `mount` over `shallow` specifically to avoid excessive and repetitive `.dive()` calls).

First export the unconnected component:

```js
export const Dashboard = (props) => {
  if (props.isSignedIn)
    return (
      <div className="dashboard">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
      </div>
    );

  return null;
}

export default connect(...)(Dashboard)
```

Then in your test, import the Dashboard component (**not** the default connected export):

```js
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import { Dashboard } from "./Dashboard"; // importing named export "Dashboard"

const initialProps = {
  isSignedIn: false
}

const wrapper = mount(<Dashboard { ...initialProps } />); // alternatively, you can use shallow here

// now manipulate the wrapper using wrapper.setProps(...);
```

or

Option 2.) **Not recommended**: Wrap the component in a real `Provider` with a real `store` and `mount` the connected HOC:

```js
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import { Provider } from "redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "../path/to/reducers";
import types from "../path/to/types";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard"; // importing connected default export

const store = createStore(rootReducer, undefined, applyMiddleware(thunk));

const initialProps = {
  isSignedIn: false
};

const wrapper = mount(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Dashboard { ...initialProps } />
  </Provider>
);

// now you'll dispatch real actions by type and expect the redux store to change the Dashboard component
```

For more testing information, please take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579262/testing-connected-components-with-enzyme/55586035#55586035), which covers a similar example (skip to the bullet points; ignore the MemoryRouter pieces; and, while the example is a bit old, the testing pattern is the same).

The reason I'd recommend option 1 over option 2 is that it's much easier to manage, as you're directly manipulating the component you're testing (not a HOC wrapping your component). Option 2 is only useful if you absolutely need to test the entire workflow of redux to the connected component. I find option 2 to be mostly overkill as you can unit test each piece (actions, reducers, and unconnected components) individually and achieve the same testing coverage. In addition, as I mentioned in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54671473/testing-simple-redux-form-with-enzyme-where-is-value/54678215#54678215), I find `redux-mock-store` to be mostly useful for unit testing redux actions.

On a side note, you can see what enzyme sees by using `console.log(wrapper.debug());` in a test!

---

Example unconnected test:

```js
import React, { createElement } from "react";
import { configure } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Dashboard } from "./App.js";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const initialProps = {
  isSignedIn: false
};

describe("Unconnected Dashboard Component", () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    /* 
      This code below may be a bit confusing, but it allows us to use
      "wrapper.setProps()" on the root by creating a function that first
       creates a new React element with the "initialProps" and then
       accepts additional incoming props as "props". 
    */
    wrapper = mount(
      createElement(
        props => (
          <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/"]}> // use memory router for testing (as recommended by react-router-dom docs: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/testing)
            <Dashboard {...props} />
          </MemoryRouter>
        ),
        initialProps
      )
    );
  });

  it("initially displays nothing when a user is not signed in", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(".dashboard").exists()).toBeFalsy();
  });

  it("displays the dashboard when a user is signed in", () => {
    wrapper.setProps({ isSignedIn: true });
    expect(wrapper.find(".dashboard").exists()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Working example (click on the `Tests` tab to run tests):

[image: Edit Simple Test]

---

Reuseable HOC wrapper:

**utils/HOCWrapper/index.js**

```js
import React, { createElement } from "react";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from './path/to/reducers';

const middlewares = applyMiddleware([thunk]);
export const store = createStore(rootReducer, null, middlewares);

/**
 * Factory function to create a mounted MemoryRouter + Redux Wrapper for a component
 * @function HOCWrapper
 * @param {node} Component - Component to be mounted
 * @param {object} initialProps - Component props specific to this setup.
 * @param {object} state - Component initial state for setup.
 * @param {array} initialEntries - Initial route entries for MemoryRouter.
 * @param {object} options - Optional options for enzyme's "mount"
 * @function createElement - Creates a wrapper around passed in component (now we can use wrapper.setProps on root)
 * @returns {MountedRouterWrapper}
 */
export const HOCWrapper = (
    Component,
    initialProps = {},
    state = null,
    initialEntries = ["/"],
    options = {},
) => {
    const wrapper = mount(
        createElement(
            props => (
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={initialEntries}>
                        <Component {...props} />
                    </MemoryRouter>
                </Provider>
            ),
            initialProps,
        ),
        options,
    );
    if (state) wrapper.find(Component).setState(state);
    return wrapper;
};

export default HOCWrapper;
```

To use it, import the HOCWrapper function:

```js
import Component from "./Example";
import HOCWrapper from "./path/to/utils/HOCWrapper"; 
// if you need access to store, then... 
// import HOCWrapper, { store } from "./path/to/utils/HOCWrapper";

const initialProps = { ... };
const initialState = { ... }; // optional (default null)
const initialEntries = [ ... ]; // optional (default "/")
const options = { ... }; // optional (default empty object)

// use the JSDoc provided above for argument breakdowns
const wrapper = HOCWrapper(Component, initialProps, initialState, initialEntries, options); // not all args are required, just the "Component"
```

Comment: Thank you @mattcarlotta, that setup in option 1 helped :) I am having a slight issue trying to update my isSigned in prop. Here is my code 

`const initialProps = {
  isSignedIn: false,
};

describe("Unconnected Dashboard Component", () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(
      <Router>
        <Dashboard {...initialProps} />
      </Router>
    );
    console.log(wrapper.debug());
  });

  it("displays the dashboard", () => {
    wrapper.setProps({ isSignedIn: true });
    expect(wrapper.find(".dashboard")).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});`

Comment: Error - Unconnected Dashboard Component › displays the dashboard
    expect(received).toHaveLength(expected)
    Expected length: 1
    Received length: 0
    Received object: {}

      22 |   it("displays the dashboard", () => {
      23 |     wrapper.setProps({ isSignedIn: true });
    > 24 |     expect(wrapper.find(".dashboard")).toHaveLength(1);
         |                                        ^
      25 |   });
      26 | });
  
  console.log
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Router history={{...}}>
        <Dashboard isSignedIn={false} />
      </Router>
    </BrowserRouter>

Comment: You won't need `Router` nor `BrowserRouter` if you're not using it within the component (unless you're using a `Link` or `useRouter`). Otherwise, your test should work as expected.

Comment: Updated my answer above for unconnected dashboard tests (look at the bottom).

Comment: thanks @mattcarlotta - your example makes sense thank you - they are still failing unfortunately. For the first test it -   Received: {} and the second one that should be true is  Received: false

It manually works as expected so I'm really not sure. When I console.debug() it gives me false both times - 

console.log
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Router history={{...}}>
        <Dashboard isSignedIn={false} />
      </Router>
    </BrowserRouter>

     p.s I had added a Link in the component.

Comment: Updated tests and added a codesandbox that includes a wrapped `react-router-dom` HOC.

Comment: This worked - thank you very much for all of your help! Greatly appreciated. Out of curiosity,  if in the the future I import any child components that are connected to the redux store, into my Dashboard component will I still be able to use mount for this? Also do you have any courses on testing or recommend any good ones? thanks again - Kim!

Comment: I've been recommending this [tutorial](https://www.udemy.com/share/101WmYA0UZdFlWQno=/). However, it's been a while and the tutorial has changed, so I'm not sure how good it is. The **best** way to learn is to find a popular npm library (like a UI library) and see how they test their components (unfortunately, again, most seem to be moving away from enzyme and toward [react-testing library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/react)).

Comment: Updated answer above to include a reuseable `HOCWrapper` function you can import for easily setting up wrapped redux/router components.

Comment: wow thats really cool, thanks a million @mattcarlotta. I've added that HOC in and tried to use it on the Dashboard component. I get this error message - Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

      28 |   options = {}
      29 | ) => {
    > 30 |   const wrapper = mount(

I'm possibly using it incorrectly?

Comment: import React from "react";
import { Dashboard } from "../dashboard/dashboard";
import { HOCWrapper } from "../../utils/HOCWrapper";

const initialProps = {
  isSignedIn: false,
};

describe("Unconnected Dashboard Component", () => {
  const wrapper = HOCWrapper(<Dashboard />, initialProps);

  it("initially displays nothing when a user is not signed in", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(".dashboard").exists()).toBeFalsy();
  });

Comment: (the rest of it) ... 
 it("displays the dashboard when a user is signed in", () => {
    wrapper.setProps({ isSignedIn: true });
    expect(wrapper.find(".dashboard").exists()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

Comment: The HOCWrapper should **NOT** be passed a JSX component (`<Dashboard />`), instead, it should just be the imported function (`Dashboard`). Please see the `HOCWrapper` example again.

Comment: On that note, if you have any other questions, feel free to send me an email: carlotta.matt@gmail.com. You'll get a quicker response and, for me, it'll be much easier to read your code when its not placed within a 500 character comment box!