# Unable to run tests on connected components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, mern

I am using MERN stack and Redux. I am trying to write some test cases for various components. For any that are connected i get an error...

"Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Subject)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to  and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(Subject) in connect options."

I have tried wrapping it in a Provider but i still get the same message. Anyone any idea how to solve this?

Test

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import Provider from "react";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import Subject from "../components/layout/Subject";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import combineReducers from "../reducers/index";
const store = createStore(combineReducers, undefined, applyMiddleware(thunk));

it("Subject should render without errors", () => {
  const component = mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Subject />
    </Provider>
  );
  const wrapper = component.find("#Subject");
  expect(wrapper.length).toBe(1);
});
```

Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import GoogleSearch from "./GoogleSearch";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchLatestSubjects } from "../../actions/subject";
import { fetchTopicSubjects } from "../../actions/subject";
import { fetchTopicComments } from "../../actions/comment";
import { fetchComments } from "../../actions/comment";
import { rateSubject } from "../../actions/subject";
import { fetchUsers } from "../../actions/authActions";
import { rateUser } from "../../actions/authActions";
import { rateComment } from "../../actions/comment";
import { trueVote } from "../../actions/subject";
import { mostlyTrueVote } from "../../actions/subject";
import { mostlyFalseVote } from "../../actions/subject";
import { halfAndHalfVote } from "../../actions/subject";
import { falseVote } from "../../actions/subject";

class Subject extends Component {
  // on loading the subjects and comments
  // are fetched from the database
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchLatestSubjects();
    this.props.fetchComments();
    this.props.fetchUsers();
    console.log(
      fetch("https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json").then((res) => res.json())
    );
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // set inital state for subjects
      // description, summary and comments all invisible
      viewDesription: -1,
      viewSummary: -1,
      comments: [],
      topic: "subjects",
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // new subject and comments are added to the top
    // of the arrays
    if (nextProps.newPost) {
      this.props.subjects.unshift(nextProps.newPost);
    }
    if (nextProps.newPost) {
      this.props.comments.unshift(nextProps.newPost);
    }
  }

  clickHandler = (id) => {
    // when a subject title is clicked pass in its id
    const { viewDescription } = this.state;
    this.setState({ comments: [] });
    var temp = [];

    // get the details of the author of the subject and save to state
    const subject = this.props.subjects.find((subject) => subject._id === id);
    const user = this.props.users.find((user) => user._id === subject.author);

    // save comments for subject to temp array
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < this.props.comments.length; i++) {
      if (this.props.comments[i].subject === id) {
        temp.unshift(this.props.comments[i]);
      }
    }

    console.log(temp);
    // for each comment add a property with the authors name
    temp.forEach((comment) => {
      var commentAuthor = this.props.users.find(
        (user) => user._id === comment.author
      );
      comment.authName = commentAuthor.name;
    });

    // save the subject id to local storage
    // this is done incase a new comment is added
    // then the subject associated  with it can be retrieved
    // and added as a property of that comment
    localStorage.setItem("passedSubject", id);
    localStorage.setItem("passedTopic", subject.topic);
    // add all changes to the state
    this.setState({
      viewDescription: viewDescription === id ? -1 : id,
      comments: temp,
      subAuthor: user.name,
      authRating: user.rating,
      authNoOfVotes: user.noOfVotes,
    });
  };

  // hovering on and off subjects toggles the visibility of the summary
  hoverHandler = (id) => {
    this.setState({ viewSummary: id });
  };
  hoverOffHandler = () => {
    this.setState({ viewSummary: -1 });
  };

  rateHandler = (id, rate, item) => {
    if (item === "subject") {
      // this function rates the subject and the author
      const subject = this.props.subjects.find((subject) => subject._id === id);
      const author = this.props.users.find(
        (user) => user._id === subject.author
      );
      // call the rateSubject and rateUser functions
      this.props.rateSubject(id, rate, subject.noOfVotes, subject.rating);
      this.props.rateUser(author._id, rate, author.noOfVotes, author.rating);
      console.log(author.name);
      alert("Thank you for rating this subject.");
    } else if (item === "comment") {
      const comment = this.props.comments.find((comment) => comment._id === id);
      const author = this.props.users.find(
        (user) => user._id === comment.author
      );
      // call the rateComment and rateUser functions
      this.props.rateComment(id, rate, comment.noOfVotes, comment.rating);
      this.props.rateUser(author._id, rate, author.noOfVotes, author.rating);
      console.log(author.name);
      alert("Thank you for rating this comment.");
    }
  };

  voteHandler = (id, currVote, vote) => {
    if (vote === "True") {
      console.log(id, currVote, vote);
      this.props.trueVote(id, currVote);
      alert("Thanks for voting!");
      window.location.reload(false);
    } else if (vote === "False") {
      console.log(id, currVote, vote);
      this.props.falseVote(id, currVote);
      alert("Thanks for voting!");
      window.location.reload(false);
    } else if (vote === "mostlyFalse") {
      console.log(id, currVote, vote);
      this.props.mostlyFalseVote(id, currVote);
      alert("Thanks for voting!");
      window.location.reload(false);
    } else if (vote === "mostlyTrue") {
      console.log(id, currVote, vote);
      this.props.mostlyTrueVote(id, currVote);
      alert("Thanks for voting!");
      window.location.reload(false);
    } else if (vote === "halfAndHalf") {
      console.log(id, currVote, vote);
      this.props.halfAndHalfVote(id, currVote);
      alert("Thanks for voting!");
      window.location.reload(false);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const subjectItems = this.props.subjects.map((subject) => {
      // if the state equals the id set to visible if not set to invisible
      var view = this.state.viewDescription === subject._id ? "" : "none";
      var hover = this.state.viewSummary === subject._id ? "" : "none";
      var comments = this.state.comments;
      var subjectAuthor = this.state.subAuthor;
      var authRating = this.state.authRating;
      var authNoOfVotes = this.state.authNoOfVotes;
      var className = "";
      if (subject.category === "Education") {
        className = "Education";
      } else if (subject.category === "Environment") {
        className = "Environment";
      } else if (subject.category === "Politics") {
        className = "Politics";
      } else if (subject.category === "Health") {
        className = "Health";
      } else if (subject.category === "Other") {
        className = "Other";
      }

      return (
        <div key={subject._id}>
          <div
            className={className}
            onMouseEnter={() => this.hoverHandler(subject._id)}
            onMouseLeave={() => this.hoverOffHandler()}
          >
            <p className="title" onClick={() => this.clickHandler(subject._id)}>
              {subject.title}
            </p>
            <p className="vote" style={{ textAlign: "Right" }}>
              Rating: {(subject.rating / subject.noOfVotes).toFixed(1)}/5
            </p>
            <p className="summary" style={{ display: hover }}>
              {subject.summary}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="truthResult" style={{ display: view }}>
            <p className="false">
              FALSE -{" "}
              {(
                (100 /
                  (subject.true +
                    subject.false +
                    subject.mostlyTrue +
                    subject.mostlyFalse +
                    subject.halfAndHalf)) *
                subject.false
              ).toFixed(1)}
              %
            </p>
            <p className="mostlyFalse">
              MOSTLY FALSE -{" "}
              {(
                (100 /
                  (subject.true +
                    subject.false +
                    subject.mostlyTrue +
                    subject.mostlyFalse +
                    subject.halfAndHalf)) *
                subject.mostlyFalse
              ).toFixed(1)}
              %
            </p>
            <p className="halfAndHalf">
              HALF AND HALF -{" "}
              {(
                (100 /
                  (subject.true +
                    subject.false +
                    subject.mostlyTrue +
                    subject.mostlyFalse +
                    subject.halfAndHalf)) *
                subject.halfAndHalf
              ).toFixed(1)}
              %
            </p>
            <p className="mostlyTrue">
              MOSTLY TRUE -{" "}
              {(
                (100 /
                  (subject.true +
                    subject.false +
                    subject.mostlyTrue +
                    subject.mostlyFalse +
                    subject.halfAndHalf)) *
                subject.mostlyTrue
              ).toFixed(1)}
              %
            </p>
            <p className="true">
              TRUE -{" "}
              {(
                (100 /
                  (subject.true +
                    subject.false +
                    subject.mostlyTrue +
                    subject.mostlyFalse +
                    subject.halfAndHalf)) *
                subject.true
              ).toFixed(1)}
              %
            </p>
          </div>

          <div className="subjectBody " style={{ display: view }}>
            <div className="leftSubjectBody">
              <div className="subjectAuthor">
                <p className="author">
                  Subject created by: {subjectAuthor} -{" "}
                  {(authRating / authNoOfVotes).toFixed(1)}/5 Star user
                  {/* <br /> {subject.date} */}
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className="subjectDescription">
                <p className="description">{subject.description}</p>
              </div>

              <div className="subjectLinks">
                Supporting Link: <br />
                <a href={subject.links} target="blank">
                  {subject.links}
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="rightSubjectBody">
              <div className="rate">
                <p>
                  <b>Rate this subject</b>
                </p>

                <button
                  onClick={() => this.rateHandler(subject._id, 1, "subject")}
                >
                  1
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() => this.rateHandler(subject._id, 2, "subject")}
                >
                  2
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() => this.rateHandler(subject._id, 3, "subject")}
                >
                  3
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() => this.rateHandler(subject._id, 4, "subject")}
                >
                  4
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() => this.rateHandler(subject._id, 5, "subject")}
                >
                  5
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="voting">
                <p>
                  Do you think this subject question is false, mostly false,
                  half and half, mostly true or true, based on the evidence
                  provided and your own reseach in the area? Please vote below
                  and leave comments.
                </p>

                <div
                  className="voteButton"
                  onClick={() =>
                    this.voteHandler(subject._id, subject.false, "False")
                  }
                >
                  FALSE
                </div>
                <div
                  className="voteButton"
                  onClick={() =>
                    this.voteHandler(
                      subject._id,
                      subject.mostlyFalse,
                      "mostlyFalse"
                    )
                  }
                >
                  MOSTLY FALSE
                </div>
                <div
                  className="voteButton"
                  onClick={() =>
                    this.voteHandler(
                      subject._id,
                      subject.halfAndHalf,
                      "halfAndHalf"
                    )
                  }
                >
                  HALF AND HALF
                </div>
                <br />
                <div
                  className="voteButton"
                  onClick={() =>
                    this.voteHandler(
                      subject._id,
                      subject.mostlyTrue,
                      "mostlyTrue"
                    )
                  }
                >
                  MOSTLY TRUE
                </div>
                <div
                  className="voteButton"
                  onClick={() =>
                    this.voteHandler(subject._id, subject.true, "True")
                  }
                >
                  TRUE
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="subjectComments">
              <p style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>Comments:</p>
              {comments.map((comment, i) => {
                return (
                  <div key={i} className="singleComment">
                    <p>
                      {comment.title} - Comment rating :{" "}
                      {(comment.rating / comment.noOfVotes).toFixed(1)}/5
                      <br />
                      {comment.comment}
                      <br />
                      Comment by : {comment.authName} - This user has a rating
                      of {(comment.rating / comment.noOfVotes).toFixed(1)}/5
                      STARS
                    </p>
                    <div className="rate">
                      Rate this comment :{" "}
                      <button
                        onClick={() =>
                          this.rateHandler(comment._id, 1, "comment")
                        }
                      >
                        1
                      </button>
                      <button
                        onClick={() =>
                          this.rateHandler(comment._id, 2, "comment")
                        }
                      >
                        2
                      </button>
                      <button
                        onClick={() =>
                          this.rateHandler(comment._id, 3, "comment")
                        }
                      >
                        3
                      </button>
                      <button
                        onClick={() =>
                          this.rateHandler(comment._id, 4, "comment")
                        }
                      >
                        4
                      </button>
                      <button
                        onClick={() =>
                          this.rateHandler(comment._id, 5, "comment")
                        }
                      >
                        5
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
              <br />
              <a href="/addcomment">
                <div className="buttonAddComment">ADD COMMENT</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div id="Subject">
        <GoogleSearch />
        {subjectItems}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Subject.propTypes = {
  fetchLatestSubjects: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  fetchTopicSubjects: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  fetchTopicComments: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  fetchComments: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  fetchUsers: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  rateSubject: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  rateComment: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  rateUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  trueVote: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  falseVote: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  subjects: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  comments: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  users: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  newPost: PropTypes.object,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  subjects: state.subjects.items,
  newSubject: state.subjects.item,
  comments: state.comments.items,
  users: state.auth.users,
  newComment: state.comments.item,
});

// export default Subject;
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  fetchLatestSubjects,
  fetchTopicSubjects,
  fetchTopicComments,
  fetchComments,
  fetchUsers,
  rateSubject, // rate subject
  rateUser,
  rateComment,
  trueVote,
  mostlyTrueVote,
  falseVote,
  mostlyFalseVote,
  halfAndHalfVote,
})(Subject, Comment);
```

Comment: Take a look at this similar question that should help answer how to test Redux connected components: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61717143/how-do-you-debug-a-shallow-rendered-enzyme-test/61720731#61720731. In short, if you want to test a redux connected component then you need to wrap your component in a redux `Provider` and give it `store`.

Comment: Thanks, i still can't get it to work. I have updated the question with my latest test code and i now get this error... Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.   

    Check the render method of `WrapperComponent`.

Comment: Where is the `Comment` component to be found? I've noticed you added it to the connect, but I can't really see where it is defined. Also, don't work with `id` in elements, react assigns it's own id's when creating the virtual dom. The easier way to handle this would be to add a data-testid and verify it's existence over `[data-testid="Subject"]`

Comment: I just notice, `Provider` should come from `react-redux` package, not from `react`

Comment: I've taken the Comment out that was a mistake. Even after changing to what you suggested I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Got it sorted now by putting { Provider } instead of Provider. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @StephanieMatheson Feel free to self answer your question, or delete it if you think it wouldn't be helpful for future questioners. Also, just for future questions, the important part of the question was the test itself. For a good question, you would ideally just present a dummy connected component that displays the same error as your real code (the real code isn't that important to share in this scenario)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how we do in React Testing Library. You can transform it to Enzyme by replacing the utility functions accordingly.

- Providing the store to the component that needs to be rendered.

```
it('renders with redux', () => {
    render(<Provider store={store}>
        <ReduxCode />
    </Provider>);

    //further code...
})
```

Comment: I have updated the question with my latest test code. I still get an error this time it is...Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.   

    Check the render method of `WrapperComponent`.